# codeigniter - routing a non existent URI

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

So in this `codeigniter` installation, I have a controller called `user`. In its `index()` I accept a user_name and show that user's profile.

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
  function index($user_name)
  {
    //show user profile...
  }
}
```

This works fine. However to view a profile the visitor has to go to: `<site>/user/john_doe`

I want the URL to be `<site>/john_doe`. I know this is not possible using the default `controller/function/arg` setup that `codeigniter` has. Can I map this in `routes`such that if a visitor types `<site>/john_doe`, the system recognizes there is no controller called `john_doe` it internally renders `<site>/user/john_doe` (however it should keep the original short url)

Also, there will be a side effect concern of what if a user creates a username called user which is already a valid controller...but I guess that is a secondary concern (can block all controller names as keywords so user cannot register one of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, by putting the following rule at the bottom of your routing file.

```
$route['/(:any)'] = "/user/index/$1";
```

It is of absolute importance that this rule be placed **at the bottom**. If you put it on top, all the URL's you enter will match the user/index controller.

Comment: That would be exactly what I am looking for! Thanks a lot!! A side question though, this will redirect everything to user/index right? which means that I will need to trap 404 manually?

Comment: I don't think it matches all - /page/product shouldn't be matched by that rule. Your best bet is to try it out.